# Update to my meteor app 1.6.1 from 1.6.0.1 failing due to @babel/runtime not found

Tags: javascript, meteor, babeljs

I updated to meteor 1.6.1 from 1.6.0.1 on win 10. Then I updated my meteor app to 1.6.1. That appeared to go ok. But when I run the app I get prompted to install @babel/runtime.

```
c:\meteor\myapp>meteor
[[[[[ c:\meteor\myapp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
W20180130-07:40:18.156(0)? (STDERR) c:\meteor\myapp\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:475
W20180130-07:40:18.905(0)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20180130-07:40:18.908(0)? (STDERR)    ^
W20180130-07:40:18.909(0)? (STDERR)
W20180130-07:40:18.910(0)? (STDERR) Error: The @babel/runtime npm package could not be found in your node_modules
W20180130-07:40:18.912(0)? (STDERR) directory. Please run the following command to install it:
W20180130-07:40:18.915(0)? (STDERR)
W20180130-07:40:18.917(0)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime
W20180130-07:40:18.918(0)? (STDERR)
W20180130-07:40:18.920(0)? (STDERR)     at babel-runtime.js (packages\babel-runtime.js:25:9)
W20180130-07:40:18.921(0)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20180130-07:40:18.922(0)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180130-07:40:18.925(0)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:132:15
W20180130-07:40:18.926(0)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:139:3
W20180130-07:40:18.928(0)? (STDERR)     at c:\meteor\myapp\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:411:36
W20180130-07:40:18.929(0)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20180130-07:40:18.931(0)? (STDERR)     at c:\meteor\myapp\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:220:19
W20180130-07:40:18.932(0)? (STDERR)     at c:\meteor\myapp\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:471:5
W20180130-07:40:18.934(0)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (c:\meteor\myapp\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:510:12)
=> Exited with code: 1
...
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

When I attempt to install it I get this error

```
c:\meteor\myapp>meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @babel/runtime@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-29T19_10_08_271Z-debug.log
```

On verge on retreating to 1.6.0.1 but would like to ideally fix this instead.

Reverted to v 1.6.0.1 in the end. My app works again. Will likely upgrade reluctantly in future :–((

Comment: How does your package.json look like after install @babel/runtime?

Comment: The issue seems to be that the nexus .npm goes to is the company's one. And the @babel\runtime is not found there.                                          `
 "dependencies": {
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.36",
  "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
  "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
  "bson": "^1.0.4",
  "contact-form": "0.0.4",
  "js-sharing-buttons": "^2.0.0",
  "shopify-buy": "^0.7.1",
  "shopify-promise": "0.0.5",
  "simpl-schema": "^1.4.1"
 }, `

Answer (score 0):

There is also some work to do in updating npm modules, and @babel/runtime is one of them.

> The babel-runtime npm package has been required for all Meteor
>   applications since Meteor 1.3. With Babel 7, babel-runtime has been
>   renamed to @babel/runtime. If you update to Meteor 1.6.1 without
>   adding @babel/runtime to your package.json dependencies, the Meteor
>   babel-runtime package will throw a helpful error that recommends
>   running meteor npm install @babel/runtime. You should follow this
>   advice!
>
> This change of names is in fact pretty convenient, because it allows
>   @babel/runtime to be installed alongside babel-runtime, in case you
>   need both for some reason; for example, if you rely on a custom Babel
>   plugin that still assumes babel-runtime is installed.
>
> Most Meteor developers should be able to remove babel-runtime after
>   adding @babel/runtime, though there’s no harm in leaving it installed,
>   since none of its modules will be bundled unless they’re used.

If you read this article from MDG it will explain what you need to do.
https://blog.meteor.com/announcing-meteor-1-6-1-50aad71da4e6

Comment: I read that article. It only seems to address happy path for the babel upgrade in that the meteor 'npm install --save @babel/runtime' cmd should just work.

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Either form your own answer or delete this altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Updated as per your request

Comment: Its when I try to add  @babel/runtime that I run in to issues. See desc above.

Comment: I think @babel/runtime needs to be referenced with the version number on it, as it's still in beta and hasn't been officially release yet. `npm install @babel/runtime@7.0.0-beta.36`

Answer (score 0):

Not a great resolution but no fix was forthcoming so I reverted to v 1.6.0.1 in the end. My app works again.

Comment: As of today, Feb 10, 2018, I was able to update my app to 1.6.1 with:    
`meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime`    
Looking at my package-lock.json dependencies I see:    
`"@babel/runtime": {"version": "7.0.0-beta.40"...}`